# how to pass runtime parameters in jquery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I m new to jquery. My requirement is to pass rowid(unique id of each record of a table) in a jquery function. I can get rowid only at runtime. so how can I bind click event to the  tag whose id is this rowid.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="`string(rowid(Gatepass))`">Upd</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="`string(rowid(Gatepass))`">Del</a>

$(what to pass here).bind('click',function(ev) {
    _operation(para1,para2); // function which is going to perfom action
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Dont expect much help if you downvote all the answers without even commenting

Comment: @Johan: I m new to this site so don't know what is this "downvote"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the id , and acording to id do what ever you want

```
  $('a').on('click',function(){

    var id = $(this).attr('id');

   if(id == //what you want)
   {
      //function 1
   } 
   else
   {
      //function 2
   }     

    return false;

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if the id comes dynamically from the server, put inside the function the same id + hash for id selctor

```
$(what to pass here) => $("'#" + string(rowid(Gatepass)) + "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are any similarities between the IDs, you can use one of the attribute selectors such as:

ID contains

```
$('[id*="something"]')
```

ID begins with

```
$('[id^="something"]')
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

A better approach would be to place all of the dynamically named anchors into a container, and then select on that:

```
<div id="container">
    <a ...></a>
    <a ...></a>
</div>
```

Then you would select all the child anchors:

```
$('#container > a').click(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find a good selector from so few HTML code. Use a class on your markup if possible:

```
<a class="roww" href="javascript:void(0)" id="`string(rowid(Gatepass))`">Upd</a>
<a class="roww" href="javascript:void(0)" id="`string(rowid(Gatepass))`">Del</a>
```

then you can use $('.roww') to query your nodes.

Here's what you can do to get the id from the event handler:

```
function( ev ) {
   //wrap the element with jQ:
   var jel = $(this);
   //Then access attributes with .attr() getter:
   var id = jel.attr('id');

   ... //do whatever you want now.
   ... // there's a quicker alternative to get the id without jQuery, simply: 
   ... // var id = this.id
}
```